# iOS update or uninstall pods from Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa, cocoapods

I wonder how I can delete or update pods in my podfile for a Xcode project?

Eg:

```
somePod => '1.2'
anotherPod => '1.5'
```

1. How do I remove/uninstall **somePod** from my Xcode project/podfile?
2. How do I update **anotherPod** in my Xcode project/podfile to a newer version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you committed the pods to a repository, if so more steps required, but basically

edit your podfile, remove the line of the pod you don't want and run pod update.

Comment: Oh its that easy, thanks! Yes I have committed my project wich contains some pods to a github repo, so how do I update then?

Comment: assuming your gitignore allows pods, after you run pod update and push to github, the pod you wanted to delete should be removed from the remote repo, but you'll need to double check.  If you have multiple branches in your repo, the undesired pod will still be in those until you merge or do the same action on those branches.

Comment: Cheers! And when it comes to update. Do I simply change the version of the pod '1.5' to '1.6' then run pod install as well?
I can't accept your answer in another 3min, but I will when the time has passed

Comment: I used pod outdated and then pod update <pod_name> which worked. Thanks anyway